# Installation problem - black screen

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I am trying to install **Ubuntu 14.04** from a bootable USB (tried from CD - same problem) on my laptop. At boot, the GRUB opened:

[image: black screen]

And then it's like the installation have stopped or something. I see only a black screen:

[image: another black screen]

My laptop is an ACER Aspire E15 (E5-573G-504H).